# Unit test for googleApi

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, google-api, sinon

I have the following code and I am trying to create unit test 
to make sure sendToGoogle function is working so I Stub  gmail.users.messages's send method and expect the method to be called by sendToGoogle method but I got this error

> AssertionError: expected send to have been called at least once, but
>   it was never called

//email.js

```
 const helper = require('./helper')

 /**
  * sendEmail - sends an email to a given address
  *
  * @param {String} to - The address of the recipient.
  * @param {String} from - The address of the sender.
  * @param {String} subject - subject of the email.
  * @param {String} bodyText - text of the email.
  **/
function sendEmail(to, from, subject, bodyText) {
  const oAuthClient = helper.getAuth(process.env.CLIENT_ID, process.env.PRIVATE_KEY, from);
  const emailLines = helper.createEmail(to, from, subject, bodyText);
  helper.sendToGoogle(oAuthClient, from, emailLines);
}

 module.exports.sendEmail = sendEmail;
```

here is helper.js which contains my code

//helper.js

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const base64 = require('base-64');
const gmail = google.gmail("v1");

 /**
  * createEmail - createEmail an email message
  *
  * @param {String} to - The address of the recipient.
  * @param {String} from - The address of the sender.
  * @param {String} subject - subject of the email.
  * @param {String} bodyText - text of the email.
  * @return {String} - Message to send.
  **/

const createEmail = function (to, from, subject, bodyText) {
  const emailLines = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
    "to: ", to, "\n",
    "from: ", from, "\n",
    "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
    bodyText
  ].join('')
  const messageBase64 = base64.encode(emailLines.trim()).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
  return messageBase64
}
  /**
   *
   *
   * @param {String} clientKey
   * @param {String} privateKey
   * @param {String} from
   * @returns
   */
  const getAuth = function (clientKey, privateKey, from) {
    return new google.auth.JWT(
      clientKey,
      null,
      privateKey,
      ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'],
      from
    );
  }
   /**
    * @param {String} oAuthClient
    * @param {String} from
    * @param {String} message
    */
   const sendToGoogle = function (oAuthClient, from, message) {
     console.log("sendtogoogle calllled")
     gmail.users.messages.send({
       auth: oAuthClient,
       userId: from,
       resource: {
         raw: message
       }
     }, function (err, resp) {
       if (!err) {
         return resp
       }
       console.error(err)

     });
   }
  module.exports.createEmail = createEmail
  module.exports.getAuth = getAuth
  module.exports.sendToGoogle = sendToGoogle
```

and this is the unittest file

//email.spec.js

```
 it ("send to gmail",function(){
   const gmail = google.gmail("v1");
   const SendStub = sinon.stub(gmail.users.messages, 'send').returns('test')
   const result = helper.sendToGoogle("oAuthClient", from,"message")
   SendStub.should.have.been.called
  })
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: which sinon version you are using?

Comment: I use sinon version 7.2.2

Comment: Calling `google.gmail("v1")` returns a different `gmail` instance so the `send` that you are stubbing in the test isn't the same as the `send` that gets called in `helper.js`

Comment: @brian-lives-outdoors So what can I do?

Comment: What testing framework are you using?  Also, are you using ES6 import or require?

Comment: I am using Mocha, I use require

Answer (score 0):

Sinon documentation is not updated, i also wasted too much time and found the solution which fine on my case.

```
    sandbox.stub(gmail.users.messages, 'send').callsFake(() => {
        return 'test';
    });
```

Comment: Does not work, I think it is related to Gmail instance as some of the comments mentioned.

Comment: you initialized google.gmail("v1") inside the sendToGoogle , so the instance of gmail does not stub, you have to initialize to outside sendToGoogle

Comment: What do you mean? 
Do you mean I have to make const gmail = google.gmail("v1")  out of the sendToGoogle scope?

Comment: yes , this is better way to initialize at top of page

Comment: I have edited the post so maybe you have a clear picture.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue by exporting gmail and import it in my test file,
so I stub the same instance.